# Making a matrix out of an array using std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, vector

I want to make a program that converts an array into matrix. I made something that sort of works but I'm not quite satisfied with the result. I am getting output that actually makes sense but I don't know what I should change to get the one I want.

The size of matrix doesn't have to be 4x4 it can be whatever in fact I want to make one that can make me a 4x4 out of an array[15].

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>

typedef unsigned int uint;

void print(const std::vector<int>& array)
{
    for(uint i=0; i< array.size(); i++)
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
}

void random(std::vector<int>& array, int size = 4)
{
    srand(time(0));
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat;
    for(uint i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(uint j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            array.push_back(rand()%10);
        }
        mat.push_back(array);
    }

    print(array);
    for(uint i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(uint j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            std::cout << mat[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

}



main()
{
    std::vector<int> A;
    random(A);
}
```

**Example of an output since it's random**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 

1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4
```

The one i would like to get would look like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16

1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

Comment: For each row, you are adding the same vector `array`. You should define a new vector for each row.

Answer (score 1):

After you've added `array` to `mat` with `mat.push_back(array)`, you need to clear `array`, otherways `array` will always grow.

```
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat;
  for (uint i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    for (uint j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
      array.push_back(rand() % 10);
    }
    mat.push_back(array);
    array.clear();       // <<<< add this
  }
```

Change the code that prints `mat` to this:

```
  for (uint i = 0; i < mat.size(); i++)
  {
    for (uint j = 0; j < mat[i].size(); j++)
    {
      std::cout << mat[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
```

and you'll see what happens if you don't call `array.clear()` as shown above.

Comment: This is all good, but i want to store my array before it clears, i want my matrix to look like an array but just split into pieces, i know how to do this with regular arrays, but i want to try to do it with vectors.

Comment: @DimitrijeDjokic have you tried what I suggested? IMO it dos what you want.

Comment: i copy-pasted it and i get this 
//empty line
//empty line
x x x x 
x x x x 
x x x x 
x x x x
X's are any numbers since its random

Comment: Also change the code that prints mat to what I've suggested in your original code and you'll see (and hopefully understand) what happens